# How can I merge dependencies in Windows Phone 8.1 Runtime Enterprise App deployment?

Tags: windows-phone-8, win-company-app

I have a Windows Phone 8.1 Runtime enterprise app (company app) to be published to the local network.

The problem is the app depends on VC++ Runtime Libraries and when I create the .APPX package a folder with the name of Dependencies is created beside the .APPX file that contains Microsoft.VCLibs.ARM.12.00.Phone.appx file.

I don't want to install the package using the PowerShell and use the -Dependencies switch as we are going to publish the app to our local network to be used by many users.

Is there any way for me to do this merge? Now when I try to install the app using the phone, the phone asks for a installation confirmation and after tapping on Install, nothing happens and the app doesn't appear in the apps list.

Thanks

Comment: The problem is not with the dependencies, because I created a simple HelloWorld app and referenced the MS VC++ Runtime Libraries and I was able to install it without any issue. Still I have the issue with the main project. Even when I try to install the appx file using Windows Phone Application Deployment Tool, I get the following error: Error - A packaging error preventing this application from installing.

Comment: I am having the same issue with a Cordova project, I believe because of a WinJS dependency. It does work when I create an `.appxbundle` rather than an `.appx`, but our MDM requires the `.appx`